# Can I connect multiple stores in Magento with OpenERP

Tags: magento, integration, magento-1.5

I have created two stores in my magento CE version 1.5. Now I want each store to be connected separately with the OpenERP. And the store data for each store should be stored in Openerp as a separate instance.

Can anyone help me out from this?

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are just want to have a Separate product for each store .
right ?
then just configure proper Categories at magento side . and you dont need to do anything more.

assign products to store wise category . 
your problem will be solve.

else magento is not supporting for store level sync as far as i know .

Comment: Hi Ruchir ... thanks for your suggestion. But my issue is that can i make a separate instance of each magento store in OpenERp . I have the Magento OpenERp Connector with me. And also let me know whether I can have different theme for different store.

Thanks In advance

Comment: i dont think so that it is possible what you are tring to do .

Comment: okay try this thing.
then i think shop level filtration can help you . try that . not tried but can have hopes .

Comment: Actually i have done integration of Magento with Open ERP and also I have create two stores in Magento. Now what i want to do is I want to Import the store data into OPenERP but the OpenERP should create a new instance for each store. So that I can have the records of each store separately into My OPenERp.

Thanks in advance

Comment: are you using your own module . then i dont have any idea about it. but for normal connectors there are things like you can Separate every thing at level of website not at level of store.

Answer (score 2):

I do not know which module you re using but following module support the feature you are expecting [Magento OpenERP Connector](https://launchpad.net/magentoerpconnect) See the multi Section on module description on project home.

Comment: Hi, I am using the same connector. Actually I am trying to maintain record of all the products in each Website as a separate instance in Open ERP.

Answer (score 1):

This module worked perfectly http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/catalog/product/view/id/16271/  i have used in my magento 1.7 store with openerp7.0 .